# Как обновлять recyclerView смещая его ниже самого progres view. Подобному как в инстаграм.

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Пример обновления в инстаграме.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

`SwipeRefreshLayout` из библиотеки Android support — «потяните чтобы обновить»
Он добавляет функционал, который один мой коллега называет «резинка от трусов», а остальные знают этот UI-паттерн под названием «потяни, чтобы обновить». Он бывает нужен, когда есть какой-то контент, который пользователь хочет часто обновлять, и может это сделать, просто потянув контент жестом вниз, а потом отпустив.

Очень похоже, что компонент был создан для GoogleNow, а потом перекочевал в support lib (очень похожа анимация).

Алгоритм простой. 
Компонент «оборачивается» вокруг `View` или `Layout`, для которого нужно сделать обновление и может содержать только одного потомка (похоже на `ScrollView`).
Устанавливается `OnRefreshListener` с одним единственным методом `onRefresh()`. Как на него реагировать — решаем сами.
Когда нужно показать, что идет обновление (и запустить анимацию), вызываем метод `setRefreshing(boolean)` и передаем ему `true`. Наиболее логичным кажется вызов метода внутри `onRefresh()`.
Когда обновление закончено, вызываем метод `setRefreshing(boolean)` и передаем ему `false`.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Логику можете написать тут:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new    SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // Do some logic
            // if (refresh is ok)
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     });
```